# Express.js - Modify request body with new hashed password

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a Register form in my React App which uses fetch to send the username, email and password to my API.

I am using Node/Express/Mongo for my API. Once I recieve the request I am adding a user into my database:

```
// Create User
MyUser.create(req.body).then(function(users){
    res.send(users);
})
```

The request body passes along the username, email and password which are inserted into my database. What I need to do is edit the password in the request body to insert my hashed password, instead of the plain text password.

How can I edit req.body.password to update this with my hashed password? Cheers.

Comment: req.body.password = hashedPassword

Comment: Oh wow, that's embarrassing. Thanks a lot that worked. Cheers!